# Indexing by discriminator and passing the object to a function

Tags: typescript

I have the following data structure:

```js
type Component1 = {
    id: 'component1'
    num: number
}

type Component2 = {
    id: 'component2'
    str: string
}

type Component = Component1 | Component2
type ComponentType = Component['id']
```

I wanted to create an object that stores functions that do different things to each type of component. I wanted to achieve this by indexing the object with the discriminator of the components, then use Extract to get the correct typing in the functions:

```js
type ComponentConfig = {
    [K in ComponentType]: (component: Extract<Component, { id: K }>) => void
}

const cfg: ComponentConfig = {
    component1(component) { // the component is correcty typed as Component1
        console.log(component.num)
    },
    component2(component) { // the component is correctly typed as Component2
        console.log(component.str)
    }
}
```

Here, component.num is correctly a number, and component.str is correctly a string. The problem is when I want to invoke one of the functions with a variable that is of type `Component`:

```js
// This is a svelte property, it will be initialized by the framework
export let component: Component

cfg[component.id](component) // TS2345: Argument of type  Component  is not assignable to parameter of type  never
```

The problem is more visible if we separate the indexing of cfg, and the invocation of the function.

```js
const fn = cfg[component.id]
fn(component) // TS2345: Argument of type  Component  is not assignable to parameter of type  never
```

Here, the type of fn is `((component: Component1) => void) | ((component: Component2) => void)`, which logically can only be invoked with an argument of type `Component1 & Component2`, however, these 2 types have no intersection, thus, this function cannot be invoked, its argument is of type `never`.

Is there any way to make this work? I mean if we look at it, it obviously should work, since index the object with the component's id, then pass the component, which surely will be the correct component for that id. One way I imagine it would work is to use a switch statement by the discriminator of the component, but I'm wondering if it is possible to solve this without it.

Comment: This is an instance of the lack of support for "correlated unions" as described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581). The recommended approach is to a refactoring to generic indexed accesses as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  Doing that here yields [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wjeZYW).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I found a similar solution, but without changing the original data structure, I'll post it soon, thank you for replying.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to wrap the access of `cfg` in a function, that ensures the compiler, that the id is the id of the component you call the resolved function with:

```js
function foo<K extends Component['id']>(id: K, component: Extract<Component, { id: K }>) {
    cfg[id](component)
}

foo(x.id, x)
```

If we separate the indexing and the function call, we can clearly see that the typing of the resolved function is now correct:

```
function foo<K extends Component['id']>(id: K, component: Extract<Component, { id: K }>) {
    const fn = cfg[id]
    fn(component)
}
```

Here the type of `fn` is correctly `ComponentConfig[K]`.

Comment: By allowing two inputs to `foo` you open up [this hole](https://tsplay.dev/weLXEW) whereby the compiler fails to notice that the two inputs might not be properly correlated.  This sort of unsoundness is generally unavoidable, but usually the recommendation is to refactor to a one-input version where this is much less likely.  In some sense this is no different from a type assertion.  If you're interested in seeing the other version written up as an answer, let me know.

Comment: Wow I did not know that. Thanks for the info. Then it’s your solution that is correct, however I can not accept it because you added it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Actually you could modify your version to [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7V1ow), which is less intense than the full refactoring.  Do you want to do that?

Comment: Wow, yes, that's acually better.